# How can I get the count of posts, without getting the content of posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, count

Is there a way of getting the number of posts from a user? I know you can get the posts from a user, but it arrives paginated, and counting through the pages would be nonsense. I don't necessarily need the content of the posts, but I would love to get how many the user has posted.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You must count the # of records. If using FQL do

```
    SELECT ' ' FROM... WHERE...
```

And FB will return empty rows.